# Reset SELECT After Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have jquery script and need function to reset the SELECT input after submited.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  //elements

  var progressbox = $("#progressbox");
  var progressbar = $("#progressbar");
  var statustxt = $("#statustxt");
  var submitbutton = $("#submit");
  var myform = $("#myForm");
  var output = $("#output");
  var completed = 'Loading...';
  $(myform).ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() { //brfore sending form
      submitbutton.attr('disabled', ''); // disable upload button
      statustxt.empty();
      progressbox.slideDown(); //show progressbar
      progressbar.width(completed); //initial value 0% of progressbar
      statustxt.html(completed); //set status text
      statustxt.css('color', '#ffffff'); //initial color of status text
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) { //on progress
      progressbar.width(percentComplete + '%') //update progressbar percent complete
      statustxt.html(percentComplete + '%'); //update status text
      if (percentComplete > 50) {
        statustxt.css('color', '#ffff00'); //change status text to white after 50%
      }
    },
    complete: function(response) { // on complete
      output.html(response.responseText); //update element with received data
      myform.resetForm(); // reset form
      submitbutton.removeAttr('disabled'); //enable submit button
      progressbox.slideUp(); // hide progressbar
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

and here are the select input option

```
<select id="jenis" name="jenis" class="select2">
    <option value="SURAT">SURAT</option>
    <option value="UNDANGAN">UNDANGAN</option>
    <option value="NOTA DINAS">NOTA DINAS</option>
</select>
```

the current script is reset all input but not the SELECT input

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working? Please try to make it clear what you need help with

Comment: Hi i need script auto reset the SELECT option after submited because the current script not work for the SELECT. option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `$('#jenis').val("");` to make your select empty or `$('#jenis').prop('selectedIndex', 0);` to select the first (or any other) value

```js
function reset() {
  $('#jenis').val("");//$('#jenis').prop('selectedIndex', 0); if you want to choose first <option>
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="jenis" name="jenis" class="select2">
    <option value="SURAT">SURAT</option>
    <option value="UNDANGAN">UNDANGAN</option>
    <option value="NOTA DINAS">NOTA DINAS</option>
</select>
<button id="reset" onclick="reset()">reset</button>
```

To reset your select when ajax is completed, you could write this:

```
$(myform).ajaxForm({
    ...
    complete: function(response) { // on complete
      $('#jenis').val(""); //clear the select
      output.html(response.responseText); //update element with received data
      myform.resetForm(); // reset form
      submitbutton.removeAttr('disabled'); //enable submit button
      progressbox.slideUp(); // hide progressbar
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry need the function run after form submited, not using the reset button

Comment: @user2430933 You can call `reset()` function from any place you want, for example from here: `complete: function(response) { reset(); ... } `. I just created a simplified example to show how it works. Check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try either of these. This gets attached to your form...

```
onsubmit="this.form.reset();"
```

This gets attached to the submit button...

```
onclick="this.form.reset();"
```

Comment: This will reset it *before* it's submitted, not after. He should do this in the `complete:` function of `ajaxForm()`.

Comment: You mean the onclick?

Comment: No, I mean `complete: function(response) { // on complete` in the code in his question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "after submit". If you mean after the AJAX operation is done, then the logical place is in the `complete` function

```
complete: function(response) { // on complete
    output.html(response.responseText); //update element with received data
    myform.resetForm(); // reset form
    submitbutton.removeAttr('disabled'); //enable submit button
    progressbox.slideUp(); // hide progressbar
    $('#jenis').val(''); // I don't know which value you consider to be the default, so this will set no value at all.
}
```